# Screen not really blanked after delay?

Tags: screen

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, whenever my inactivity delay kicks in, my screen seems to go blank, but it is not really black, as is noticeable in a dark room. As a result, my monitor's energy saving doesn't become active.

I can manually set the delay with 'xset dpms 300 400 600', which works as expected, exactly once, but as soom as the screen is reactivated,  the problem is back, and I need to xset again.

Any help on this is appreciated...

Comment: Does this key still exist?  `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness`

Comment: Yes, this key exists, its value is 30.

Comment: Can you try to make it lower? I have no gnome3 anymore. `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 0`

Comment: This makes no difference

Comment: I totally forgot; snap stuff in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed by a recent update, either in Ubuntu or something Gnome.